# Why does List<T>.Sort(IComparer<T>) and List<T>.Sort(Comparison<T>) handle corner cases differently?

Tags: c#, .net, sorting

1, `Sort(IComparer<T>)` will try to use `Comparer<T>.Default` when its parameter is null.
`Sort(Comparison<T>)` will throw an `ArgumentNullException`.
Is there any reason against trying to use `Comparer<T>.Default.Compare` when the comparison parameter is null?

2, `Sort(IComparer<T>)` won't throw an exception for lists with less than two elements even if T is not `IComparable`.
On the other hand, `Sort(Comparison<T>)` always throws `ArgumentNullException` when the parameter is null.
Shouldn't this method allow the same sort of looseness?

Comment: You can compare null == null but how do you sort a item that is null?

Comment: I don't understand the question. You are sorting the list and that is not null. What is null is either the `IComparer<T>` parameter or the `Comparer<T>` parameter.

Comment: `Comparison<T>` is a delegate type, but the Sort() algorithm needs an IComparer to get its job done.  So the delegate is wrapped by a little helper class, Array.FunctorComparer.  That wrapper will crash with a very hard to diagnose internal NRE if the null test isn't done.

Comment: @HansPassant Interesting point, though I still fail to see any reason against using `Comparer<T>.Default.Compare` as fallback. Do you mean, the default _could_ be null as well ?

Comment: No.  History is murky but these kind of null tests tend to get added afterwards, when they get enough bug reports from testers or programmers that got it wrong and couldn't figure out what they did wrong.  By then it is too late to change the design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why does List.Sort(IComparer) and List.Sort(Comparison)
>   handle corner cases differently?

Because the programmers of those functions decided so. After it was decided, the behavior could no longer be changed without breaking existing code. The only way to change it would have been to deprecate the entire class to make a new one. And this miniscule issues was not worth anything close that kind of effort.

Unless they or someone from back in that age happens to be around by chance, guessing their reasons would be just that - guessing.

Welcome to technical debt/historically grown issues. You will find those in every language, every library. By all effort and resources that went into developing it, .NET is not an exception.

That being said, on to guessing/professional opinion:

> Is there any reason against trying to use Comparer.Default.Compare when the comparison parameter is null?

Is there any reason to throw a Invalid Cast exception/compiler error, rather then implicitly casting? Yes, because Implicit operations caused all kinds of issues in the 60-ish years of programming history. Being to agressive with "fixes" is exactly what caused the PHP and Javascript examples in this [comic](http://www.sandraandwoo.com/2015/12/24/0747-melodys-guide-to-programming-languages/). Hint: JS does the wrong thing in *both* cases. One just happens to get the right result by chance.

Nothing is a dumb, as code that tries to be smart. Trying to fix a input variable yourself - especially a null value - is a case of trying to be smart. If they *wanted* the default comparer, they could just use the parameterless Sort(). And checking a value for null before handing it to a function as argument is trivial.

Exceptions are for errors the progammer should not ignore. Giving a null value is right up there in this area.

Comment: Thank you. I started with `Sort(IComparer<T>)` in my own sorter and tried to apply its behavior on `Sort(Comparison<T>)` instead of the other way around. Both throwing on null is a great idea. What about not throwing on less than two elements? Do you consider that trying to be smart, or expected behavior?

Comment: @ubacs Throwing on less then 2 elements, is okay-ish. On the hand, it is propably easiest to just give the input back because it is already "as sorted as it can be". On the other hand, the warning that this Array might be a whole lot shorter then expected by the programmer might avoid issues down the line. | Checking for that is relatively easy. It is just a 3rd condition next to "is the array reference not null?" and "is the sorter not null?" So it does not qualify for a Vexing exception.

Comment: It looks like not throwing on less than 2 elements is more of a side effect. `Comparer<T>.Default` returns an `ObjectComparer<T>` whose `Compare` method will throw if T is not `IComparable`, but of course it won't be called.  I think I will choose consistently throwing if the type is not right over consistently working for any type as long as the number of elements is right.

Comment: @ubacs I too would rather throw Exceptions, then try to work with wrong input. As long as it is not a Vexing exception (looking at you, Parse()), agressive Exceptions are not generally a bad thing.